# Why is my web api Post controller not receiving facebook webhook leadgen info?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api2, webhooks

I am new to this! Webhooks is on the rise and at work we are generating leads. I have a 'GET' controller in web api 2 and this verifies my app and indeed I do get values for hub.verify_token, hub.challenge and hub.mode. GET controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]Hub hub){}
```

Please note: I am using C# and web api 2

Now, my problem is that facebook doesn't even hit my post. When I check the WADLogsTable in Azure storage explorer, there is information about my get request which I recorded. However there isn't even an error about the POST, even though the post controller has Trace.TraceError(). Therefore POST is not being hit. I have a feeling that my data structure is wrong. Here is my post controller and in-line with the facebook docs: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks" (Receiving Updates), I have structured my code as follows:

1. POST controller:

   ```
   public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Entry[] entry){...}
   ```
2. Entry class:

   ```
   public class Entry
   {
       public string id { get; set; }
       public string[] changed_fields { get; set; }
       public Change[] changes { get; set; }
       public DateTime time { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Change class

   ```
   public class Change
   {
       public string field { get; set; }
       public LeadInfo value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. LeadInfo class

   ```
   public class LeadInfo
   {
       public string ad_id { get; set; }
       public string adgroup_id { get; set; }
       public DateTime created_time { get; set; }
       public string form_id { get; set; }
       public string leadgen_id { get; set; }
       public string page_id { get; set; }

   }
   ```

Please note that the public props are lowercase so that they match the variable names send from Facebook.

IS my data structure correct?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Facebook sends the data in the POST request body as application/json as opposed to the usual urlencoded in HTML forms. Therefore the raw content must be read and deserialized.

Comment: @Nkosi why are you downvoting me? I stated clearly that I am new to this and was unaware of formatting. Get a life!

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your model. I found the json response by going to this page to make a test lead from your form.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class WebHookResponseModel
{
    public Entry[] entry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string _object { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public Change[] changes { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public int ad_id { get; set; }
    public long form_id { get; set; }
    public long leadgen_id { get; set; }
    public int created_time { get; set; }
    public long page_id { get; set; }
    public int adgroup_id { get; set; }
}
```